# Building a MINLP Heuristic Model in Python

Tags: heuristics, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

I am currently building a MINLP model which has around 200k decision variables and upto 100 constraints. I have access to only open source solvers which are BONMIN and COUENNE.
When I try to solve the problem, I see that the solver keeps on running for more than 2 hours. 
I have been reading the BONMIN documentation and there I see various heuristic algorithms as options. I wanted to know is there any options list i can pass to this BONMIN solver which will trigger a heuristic algorithm that will give me a suboptimal solution in ~15 minutes?

I am working with the Pyomo package.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

See this section of the Pyomo documentation on sending options to a solver: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working_models.html#sending-options-to-the-solver

Comment: I am also looking for an option list which will trigger a heuristic algorithm

Comment: Available options are solver specific and you should refer to the solver documentation to see what is available.